# Can't debug from VS Studio 2015 after updating to ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I updated my project to latest Asp.net core 1.1.
After some adjustments to configuration now I'm able to debug and compile from VS Code. However, I'm not able to debug (but can build) in VS 2015.

In VS 2015 is displaying  "References (Errors - see Error List)" which is showing the following:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key:
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App

This is my current global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
}
```

And my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.11.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Dapper": "1.50.2",
    "BCrypt.Net-Core": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "dnxcore50"
      ]
    }
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Is there any change to Debug again from VS Studio 2015?

Comment: Based on the recent news, it seems that final .NET Core support would only come in VSCode and VS2017. Don't waste your time in VS2015 if the other two are your better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have NETCoreApp listed in 2 places, once in the main dependencies section and once in the framework specific dependencies below netcoreapp. I would remove the one below netcoreapp and change the one in the main dependencies section like this:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
```

Comment: What is the difference leaving this in dependencies subsection of frameworks and the main dependencies section?

Comment: generally use the main section, but in some cases you may need different or additional dependencies per framework. if I recall correctly I needed these extra xml and linq references for the desktop framework targets in this [project.json](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Syndication/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Syndication/project.json)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible they are cached in `project.lock.json`. Delete that file and rebuild and the issue should go away.